# EF Core Migration Failure: Error Number:4902,State:1,Class:16

Tags: c#, razor, entity-framework-core

I recently rolled back an EF Core migration, which deleted an existing database table, called the "Tag" table, with a Foreign Key to a "Subject" table.

The "Subject" table has a one to many relationship with a "Tag" table.

One Subject has many Tags.

When attempting to "update-database" to re-establish (re-create) the Tag table, with the Foreign Key, I receive the following error:Error Number:4902,State:1,Class:16, and the migration fails.

The Tag table does not exist.  It was deleted as a result of the migration rollback.

```
public class Subject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Color { get; set; }        
    }


   public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Narrative { get; set; }

        public int SubjectId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }      
    }

Here is my migration:

public partial class AddTagToDb : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Tag_Subject_SubjectId",
                table: "Tag");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "SubjectId",
                table: "Tag",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(int),
                oldNullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Narrative",
                table: "Tag",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldNullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Description",
                table: "Tag",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldNullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Tag_Subject_SubjectId",
                table: "Tag",
                column: "SubjectId",
                principalTable: "Subject",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Tag_Subject_SubjectId",
                table: "Tag");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "SubjectId",
                table: "Tag",
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(int));

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Narrative",
                table: "Tag",
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(string));

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
                name: "Description",
                table: "Tag",
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(string));

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Tag_Subject_SubjectId",
                table: "Tag",
                column: "SubjectId",
                principalTable: "Subject",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        }

Error message encountered after update-migrtation:

PM> update-database
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]');
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [MigrationId], [ProductVersion]
      FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]
      ORDER BY [MigrationId];
Applying migration '20190804003447_AddTagToDb'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations[20402]
      Applying migration '20190804003447_AddTagToDb'.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      ALTER TABLE [Tag] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Tag_Subject_SubjectId];
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "Tag" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:4c476313-8831-48bc-b88d-e6979ff701bf
Error Number:4902,State:1,Class:16
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [Tag] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Tag_Subject_SubjectId];
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "Tag" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:4c476313-8831-48bc-b88d-e6979ff701bf
Error Number:4902,State:1,Class:16
Cannot find the object "Tag" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Comment: The migration you've shown doesn't seem to match the explanation, i.e. there is no `CreateTable` / `DropTable` in it which would be the case if the table was created (and respectively deleted) by that migration. Instead, it tries to make 3 columns of an *existing* table non nullable. If the table is deleted, that definitely is not by this migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AddForeignKey operations use the new table name and after those new operations which causes an exception. To work, just change the table name to the new name in the generated [migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) file.

Comment: Tom,
I appreciate the response but do not understand your fix.
The code below looks correct to me...

    >migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    >name: "FK_Tag_Subject_SubjectId",
    >table: "Tag",
    >column: "SubjectId",
    >principalTable: "Subject",
    >principalColumn: "Id",
    >onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);`

Comment: 'Cannot find the object "Tag" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.' try to change the permission of database in SQL server, steps are Open SQL server management studio > Database > your database name > properties > permission